# PlatformNotSupportedException when blinking LED using FDD, works using SCD

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, publish, gpio

I've recently got a Raspberry Pi (3B+ and 4) and have been trying to get a .Net Core application working using the [System.Device.Gpio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Gpio) package, having followed along with [a post on Scott Hanselman's blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingTheNETCore2xSDKOnARaspberryPiAndBlinkingAnLEDWithSystemDeviceGpio.aspx). I'm publishing from my dev machine and scp'ing the files over to the pi.

If I do a SCD (Self Contained Deployment) by using `dotnet publish -r linux-arm` and copy the many many files over to the Pi, I can run the application and the LED blinks as expected.

However, I'm trying to do a `dotnet publish` to create a FDD (Framework Depdendent Deployment), but copying those files over and doing `dotnet ./BlinkLed.dll` causes a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` to be thrown by `new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Board)`.

My understanding was that the only difference between a FDD and a SCD is that the former requires an installed .Net Core runtime, I can't see anything mentioned about some apps only working in a SCD in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/). I've installed this on the Pi, and can `dotnet ./<SomeDll>` for a simple hello world application that prints to the console, it just doesn't seem to work if I try to use the `System.Device.Gpio` package. As I'm trying to set up a decent remote debugging experience it would be ideal if I can do a FDD as it generates far fewer files, meaning that there's less to copy to the Pi each publish/debug cycle.

The `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Threading;

namespace LedBlink
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello LedBlink!");

            using(var gpioController = new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Board)) // <-- This is where the exception is thrown
            {
                var pin = 11;

                gpioController.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);

                try
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        gpioController.Write(pin, PinValue.High);
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        gpioController.Write(pin, PinValue.Low);
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    gpioController.ClosePin(pin);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So to summarise, my app works if I do a Self Contained Deployment, but not if I do a Framework Dependent Deployment, and I'd like to do a Framework Dependent Deployment.